# How to type hint args and kwargs, if not unpacking, in most general form?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, iterable-unpacking

Let's say I want to pass `args` and `kwargs` to a function *without* using `*args` and `**kwargs`.

In the event, what is the most general type hint to use?

Is it `Iterable` for `args` and `Mapping` for `kwargs`?

---

**Sample Code**

Here is some sample code made using Python 3.8.

```py
from typing import Mapping, Iterable

def foo(*args, **kwargs) -> None:
    pass

def foo_dispatcher(foo_args: Iterable, foo_kwargs: Mapping) -> None:
    foo(*foo_args, **foo_kwargs)

foo_dispatcher([0], {"ham": 1})
```

Comment: Remember that typing hints are comments; the code has to run without them.  In this case, it's not really "args" and "kwargs", you're just passing a list and a dict.  I would think the notations you've chosen are correct, if confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know your actual arguments and kwargs then you can obviously use the specifics, including `TypedDict` for the the arguments.

In this most-general case you you can use `Iterable` and `Mapping[str, object]`.

For known functions over-typing is quite possible here, thanks to named non-keywords, variable length positional arguments, etc.  You may not want to disallow `def foo(a, b, c=4)` being called as `foo(1, b=1, c=2)`